# pymodbus starttcpserver - how do I restrict access

Tags: python, pymodbus, pymodbustcp

I have a bit of code from pymodbus:

```
store = ModbusSlaveContext(hr=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [0]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

if debug:
    print('pymobus in debug')
    pymodbus_apply_logging_config("DEBUG")

# Start the Modbus server on the specified TCP port
try:
    print(f'Starting ModbusTCP server at port {port}.')
    StartTcpServer(context=context, address=("0.0.0.0", port))
```

How do I set up an access list to restrict which IP addresses the clients are connecting from?

I been googling, but documentation is poor :-(.

I have been googling everywhere but no luck. I want to set up an access list but I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is already developed.   But your request is good.
In my case, after executing  StartTcpServer,  the script is blocked, even if I excecute it in a thread.   Server is running properly (I can read and write in the modbus table ...)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35476178)